# PHP/MySql Update Will Not Work

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have created 2 pages

```
update.php
edit.php
```

we start on  edit.php so here is edit.php's script

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

mysql_connect('mysql13.000webhost.com', 'a2670376_Users', 'Password') or     die(mysql_error());
echo "MySQL Connection Established! <br>";

mysql_select_db("a2670376_Pass") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Database Found! <br>";

$query = "UPDATE members SET username = '$username', fname = '$fname', 
password = '$password' WHERE id = '$id'";

$res = mysql_query($query);

if ($res)
echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
else
echo "Problem updating record. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
?>

<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id;?>">
ScreenName:<br> <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength='25'   style='width:247px' name="username" value="<?=$username;?>"/><br>
FullName:<br> <input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' maxlength='20' style='width:248px'     name="ud_img" value="<?=$fname;?>"/><br>
Email:<br> <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength='50' style='width:250px'    name="ud_img" value="<?=$email;?>"/><br>
Password:<br> <input type='text' name='password' id='password' maxlength='25'     style='width:251px' value="<?=$password;?>"/><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

now here is the update.php page where i am having the MAJOR problem

```
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect('mysql13.000webhost.com', 'a2670376_Users', 'Password') or   die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a2670376_Pass") or die(mysql_error());

$id = (int)$_SESSION["id"];

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);


$query="UPDATE members
SET username = '$username', fname = '$fname', email = '$email', password = '$password'
WHERE id='$id'";


mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
echo "<p>($id) Record Updated<p>";
}else{
echo "<p>($id) Not Updated<p>";
}
?>
```

now on edit.php i fill out the form to edit the account "test" while i am logged into it now once the form if filled out i click on |Submit!| button
and it takes me to update.php and it returns this

```
(0) Not Updated  

(0) <= id of user logged in

Not Updated <= MySql Error from  


mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
```

i want it to update the user logged in and if i am not mistaken in this script it says

```
  $id = (int)$_SESSION["id"];
```

witch updates the user with the id of the person who is logged in

but it isnt updating its saying that no tables were effected

if it helps heres my MySql Database picture
just click here  http://i50.tinypic.com/21juqfq.png

even with

```
session_start();
```

it wont work returns the same thinf as before

Comment: sql injections are possible i know that ill fix that as soon as i git this to work

Comment: try echoing your full sql update statement and see what it is trying to run

Answer (score 1):

it appears that you have not started your session, therefore `$_SESSION['id']` is not set.

```
session_start();
```

And, as always don't use mysql_* functions, that time has gone. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: where do i put session_start();

Comment: at the very top, just below your opening `<?php` tag. And thats on your update.php page

Comment: thanks i did that and tested it it still wont work same thing as before

Comment: Right, again it could be that you didn't start your session on your edit.php page as well. Any time that you use a $_SESSION you need to ensure that you start the session, so that you can pick the variables up as you go from page to page.

Comment: a simple test is to do `print_r($_SESSION)` and see what data is being kept inside of the $_SESSION variable

Comment: i did that i got Updatedprint_r(Array)

Comment: i mean print_r(Array) sorry i copied to much

Comment: it is not an echo statement.

Comment: print_r(Array) showed up on update.php also i put it in all output fields

Comment: so now what? could i even make this work or do i have to use a diffrent one

Comment: you need to ensure that you sessions are carrying across each page. that is the first step. once you have achieved that,  then you will be able to use your `id` var to update your table.

Comment: i have a file named connect.php with connection info so maby require_once ("connect.php") to ensure connections across each page?

Comment: $_SESSION[username] i put that in the output slots and it shows my username i am logged into as so whats the problem if its not connection

Comment: nothing shows if i use the id one.. did you look at my database picture if not please do cause id is an auto incriment to tag them could that be why it dosent show?

Comment: fni.site11.com is my site if you want to see the edit and update page you have to do the /edit.php and /update.php manualy

Answer (score 0):

it seems your session might have times out or you did not even initialize it at all.

from your output it shows the id is 0 so there is your problem